# MYSQL query using a set of values (values stored from a session array) not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a beginner and I'm doing a project (a shopping cart). User can add a product to the cart and the id of the product stores in a session. When I use those ids to echo out PRICE from DB it's not working. I'm using PHP & MYSQL. Here is my code

```
if(count($_SESSION['cart_items'])>0){
// getting the product ids
$nos = "";
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $no=>$value){
    $nos = $nos . $no . ",";
}
// removing the last comma
$nos = rtrim($nos, ',');
                         //echo $nos; (will display like this INT VALUES  1,2,3,4)
$nos=mysql_real_escape_string($nos);
$site4->DBlogin();
$qry = "SELECT * FROM vendorproducts WHERE product_no IN('.implode(',',$nos).')";        
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['price'];
}
```

Comment: please ask a more specific question. what is not working? are you getting any errors, or what unexpected behaviour are you getting? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not recursively embeddable:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM vendorproducts WHERE product_no IN('.implode(',',$nos).')";        
       ^---start of string                                    end of string ---^
```

Since you're already in a string, `.implode(...)` is just plain text, **NOT** executable code.

This means your query is illegal/invalid SQL, and if you had even basic/minimal error checking, would have been told about this:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue and thanx MARC for your suggestions.
I was making two mistakes:- IMPLODE input field was not an array. and as Marc said the query was not executable.

Changes made :-

```
$nos = rtrim($nos, ',');
**$narray = array($nos);**
$fgmembersite4->DBlogin();
$qry = **'SELECT * FROM vendorproducts WHERE product_no IN     ('.implode(',',$narray).')'**;
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
**while (**$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['price'];}
```